# Doesn't return incoming call number

Tags: android

My BroadcastReceiver class is not returning the String response.
Did i miss anything, TIA

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
        showToast(context,"Call started...");
    }
    else if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
        showToast(context,"Call ended...");
    }
    else if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
        String number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        showToast(context,"Ringing "+number);
    }
}
```

Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
<receiver android:name=".CallReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out with this code :

First make this changes in manifest.

```
      android:name=".CallReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="1">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:priority="2">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then in your broadcast :

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
  if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"))
   { number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
    Log.i("incoming", ""+number);
   Toast.makeText(context, ""+number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"))
      { outgoingPhoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
   Log.i("outgoing", ""+outgoingPhoneNumber);
    // Toast.makeText(context, ""+outgoingPhoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state))
    {   
        //Your code whatever you want to do

    }   

 }
```